# ajax call within another ajax call in jquery is not firing intermittently

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

The webmethod (SaveSalaryDetails) in the 2nd ajax call is not getting called intermittently. If I am debugging the javascript/jquery, it gets fired. Below is the code:

```
    function fnCheckAndSaveSalary() {
    debugger;
    var salary = document.getElementById("   <%=txtSelEmployeeSalary.ClientID %>").value;
    var employeeID = $find("<%=rcmbEmployees.ClientID %>").get_value();
    var employeeName = $find("<%=rcmbEmployees.ClientID %>").get_text();
    var paidDate = $find("<%=radPayDate.ClientID %>").get_selectedDate();
    //var lblStatus = document.getElementById("<%=lblStatus.ClientID %>");
    //setTimeout(saveSalary, 15000);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ EmpID: employeeID, PaidDate: paidDate }),
        url: 'Pay.aspx/IsSalaryExisting',
        success: function(response) {
            debugger;
            alert("Checked for records" + response.d);
            //debugger;
            //No record exists for the particular month and year for the employee
            if (response.d == false) {
                debugger;
                alert("Now saving..");
                saveSalary(salary, employeeID, paidDate);
            }
            else {
                //debugger;
                alert('Salary already exists for Employee:' + employeeName + ' for date:' + paidDate);
            }
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function saveSalary(salary, employeeID, paidDate) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ Salary: salary, EmpID: employeeID, PaidDate: paidDate }),
        url: 'Pay.aspx/SaveSalaryDetails',
        success: function(response) {
            //debugger;
            alert('Successfully saved');
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert('Error in saving the salary details' + response.d);
        }
    });
}


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
<div>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Select Employee:</td>
    <td><telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcmbEmployees" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcmbEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Salary: </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSelEmployeeSalary" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pay Date:</td>
    <td><telerik:RadMonthYearPicker ID="radPayDate" runat="server"  
    MinDate="1/1/2000" MaxDate="1/1/3000"></telerik:RadMonthYearPicker></td>
</tr>
</table> 
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="fnCheckAndSaveSalary()" />
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind file:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static int SaveSalaryDetails(string Salary, string EmpID, string PaidDate)
    {
        //saves details in the database and returns ID

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return objEmpSalaryObj.PaymentID;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool IsSalaryExisting(string EmpID, string PaidDate)
    {
        EmployeeController objController = new EmployeeController();
        EmployeePayHistoryVo objEmpSalaryObj = new EmployeePayHistoryVo();
        bool salaryExists = false;
        try
        {
            objEmpSalaryObj.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(EmpID);
            objEmpSalaryObj.PaidMonth = (Convert.ToDateTime(PaidDate)).ToString("MMMM");
            objEmpSalaryObj.PaidYear = (Convert.ToDateTime(PaidDate)).Year;

            salaryExists = objController.IsSalaryExisting(objEmpSalaryObj);
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return salaryExists;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting the "Now saving" alert, even when it isn't getting called? And do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No. There are no errors in the console. I don't get any alerts either.

Comment: basically you can just combine the two method in one..

Answer (score 0):

Backend

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static int IsSalaryExisting(string EmpID, string PaidDate, string Salary)
    {

        EmployeeController objController = new EmployeeController();
        EmployeePayHistoryVo objEmpSalaryObj = new EmployeePayHistoryVo();
        var salaryExists = 0;
        try
        {
            objEmpSalaryObj.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(EmpID);
            objEmpSalaryObj.PaidMonth = (Convert.ToDateTime(PaidDate)).ToString("MMMM");
            objEmpSalaryObj.PaidYear = (Convert.ToDateTime(PaidDate)).Year;

            return !objController.IsSalaryExisting(objEmpSalaryObj) ? SaveSalaryDetails(Salary, EmpID, PaidDate) : 0;
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return salaryExists;
    }
```

your JS code

```
function fnCheckAndSaveSalary() {
    debugger;
    var salary = document.getElementById("   <%=txtSelEmployeeSalary.ClientID %>").value;
    var employeeID = $find("<%=rcmbEmployees.ClientID %>").get_value();
    var employeeName = $find("<%=rcmbEmployees.ClientID %>").get_text();
    var paidDate = $find("<%=radPayDate.ClientID %>").get_selectedDate();   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ EmpID: employeeID, PaidDate: paidDate }),
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert("Now saving..");
        },
        url: 'Pay.aspx/IsSalaryExisting',
        success: function(response) {
            debugger;
            alert("Checked for records" + response.d);
            //debugger;
            //No record exists for the particular month and year for the employee
            if (response.d > 0) {
                debugger;
                alert('Successfully saved');                
            }
            else {
                //debugger;
                alert('Salary already exists for Employee:' + employeeName + ' for date:' + paidDate);
            }
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: just check the response if it has a property "d" or else you can get the result in "response" itself

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code as you suggested. Now I have only one ajaxcall. It is displaying "Nowsaving" alert each time before the method is called. But after the method "IsSalaryExisting" is called, the alert messages in the success part ("Checked for records") are still not displaying sometimes.

Comment: try to use bootstrap modal dialog instead of alert.

Comment: you can use this http://bootboxjs.com/ and just call bootbox.alert(""Checked for records" + response.d); and as well as other alerts.

Comment: I set async=false and now it is showing the alert messages every time.. Reference: http://code-tricks.com/jquery-ajax-success-callback-is-not-working-for-json-data-type/

Comment: I'd said that would be not good approach since the goal of the ajax is to be asynchronous, then your are turning that off. " Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. " http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/